# How to install git patch of Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key?

Tags: magento2, patches, installation, authorize.net, git

I am using Magento2.3 and download the Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key Patch file and put it to magento's  root directory then go to the putty and run below command:

```
patch --p0<patch_file_name.patch
```

It is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now Apply Patch directly in vendor folder
This patch is applicable on all **Magento 2.x and 1.x versions**.

Alternatively you can use patched files from following address and replace them in your vendor folder.

https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Magento-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-Patch-for-M1-M2

If Need Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;`

After apply patch you will see *Signature Key*
[image]